# Notifying threads to exit

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, threadpool

Here is a simple (and possibly naive) implementation of a thread pool.

I would like to know if, given the approach below, there is a nice way to actively notify the threadpool threads to exit, rather than having to check the boolean `mStopped` after each timeout.

I understand that there are better ways of implementing a threadpool - but I am still interested in seeing if the code below could be improved without fundamentally changing it.

I'm happy to hear general suggestions... not necessarily fixes to the code below... the question is really about signaling/waiting on threads, the threadpool is just to give some context.

I'm using gcc 4.4.6 (so some of the syntax below is a little out of date), and the code is compiled with `g++ --std=c++0x main.cc -pthread`

```
#include <vector>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <deque>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

struct ThreadPool;

struct Worker {
  ThreadPool& mThreadPool;
  Worker(ThreadPool& threadPool) : mThreadPool(threadPool) {}
  void operator()();
};

struct ThreadPool {
  vector<thread> mWorkers;
  deque<function<void()>> mTasks;
  bool mStopped; // not atomic
  mutex mMutex;
  condition_variable mCond;

  ThreadPool() : mStopped(false) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; i++)
      mWorkers.push_back(thread(Worker(*this)));
  }

  ~ThreadPool() { stop();  }

  void stop() {
    if (!mStopped) {
      mStopped = true;
      for (auto it = mWorkers.begin(); it != mWorkers.end(); ++it)
        if (it->joinable()) it->join();
    }
  }

  bool canBreakFromWait() const { return !mTasks.empty(); }

  void enqueue(function<void()> f) {
    if (mStopped) return;
    unique_lock<mutex> lck(mMutex);
    mTasks.push_back(f);
    mCond.notify_one();
  }
};

void Worker::operator()() {
  while (true) {
    unique_lock<mutex> lck(mThreadPool.mMutex);
    mThreadPool.mCond.wait_for(lck, chrono::seconds(1), bind(&ThreadPool::canBreakFromWait, &mThreadPool));
    if (mThreadPool.mStopped) break;
    auto task = mThreadPool.mTasks.front();
    mThreadPool.mTasks.pop_front();
    lck.unlock();
    task();
  }
}

void doWork(int data) {}

int main() {
  ThreadPool threadPool;
  for (auto i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    threadPool.enqueue(bind(doWork, i));
  threadPool.stop();
}
```

Comment: All of the accesses to `mStopped` must be synchronized.

Comment: Thanks James. I agree that they should be in general, but I don't think this affects the example given (i.e. a misread of mStopped isn't catastrophic in this case). Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: The standard says undefined behavior.  At a much lower level, in theory, you might never see it `true` in one of the threads.  (In practice...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two comments.

The first is that since `mStopped` is modified in one thread,
and accessed in other threads, all access to it must be
synchronized.  As it stands, your program has undefined
behavior.  Whether this will be a problem in practice, I don't
know; a priori, a compiler could deduce in `stop` that no other
thread accesses the variable, and that it's not accessed in the
thread calling `stop` after the function returns, and so
suppress the assignment.

The second is that in cases where I have a job list, I've
generally found it simplest to create a special job which
terminates the thread.  The standard threads don't seem to have
a `thread_exit` function, but this can easily be simulated by
either having the job return a boolean or by using exceptions.
The `stop` function then locks the mutex, empties the queue, and
inserts one of these special termination jobs into the queue
for each thread.

Comment: Locking the queue, draining it, then putting in a terminating job, seems like an excellent approach.